# openapi: referring to an existing example in a list

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an OpenAPI 3.0.0 spec with a `Widget` component, which includes an `example` section:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Widget:
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
        cost:
          type: float
      example:
        id: 1234
        description: An example widget
        cost: 0.10
```

I'm adding a `Warehouse` component that includes a list of `Widgets`.  Is there a way to make use of the `example` on the `Widget` schema in the `Warehouse` schema?  Something like:

```
    Warehouse:
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        location:
          type: string
        widgets:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Widget'
      example:
        id: 4321
        widgets:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Widget'
```

The above didn't work.  I looked at moving the `example` out of the `Widget` schema and into a `#/components/examples/WidgetExample`, but I still wasn't sure what the syntax would look like to refer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `example` keyword does not support `$ref`.

What you can do instead is change the `Warehouse` schema to use property-level examples for properties other than `widgets`, in this case the example for `widgets` will be "inherited" from the `Widget` schema. At least this is how it works in Swagger UI and Swagger Editor.

```yaml
    Warehouse:
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          example: 4321   # <----
        location:
          type: string
          example: Sample location   # <----
        widgets:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Widget'
```

Swagger UI will display the following example for `Warehouse` in the requests and responses:

```json
{
  "id": 4321,
  "location": "Sample location",
  "widgets": [
    "id": 1234,
    "description": "An example widget",
    "cost": 0.1
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the erroneous syntax in the question; that was a transcription typo.